# Autowire members of a class that refuses to auto-wire

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a class "ReportEverythingForm" which refuses to instantiate a class "ReportQueryDetailsDAO" by autowired annotation.
If I add a hack that instantiates the class "ReportQueryDetailsDAO" by "new", then the class "reportQueryDetailsDAO" will in turn not instantiate its autowired fields, like the entity manager, which then will cause a null exception.

```
@Component
public class ReportEverythingForm
{
    @Autowired
    ReportQueryDetailsDAO reportQueryDetailsDAO;

    public ReportEverythingForm() {
        //reportQueryDetailsDAO = new ReportQueryDetailsDAO();//HACK FIXME Autowired is null
    }
```

The class "ReportEverythingForm" is instantiated and called by the controller class "MonitorReportController". The autowiring seems to work here.

```
@Controller
public class MonitorReportController
{
    @Autowired
    private ReportEverythingForm reportEverythingForm;

@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/reportEverything", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getReportEverything(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session, Locale locale)
{
    //code which calls methods of "reportEverythingForm"
```

How can I get the autowiring to work? It works in other parts of the code, so it isn't a general problem I guess.

Some of the relevant imports are these:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```

The contents of "ReportQueryDetailsDao" as requested:

```
@Repository
public class ReportQueryDetailsDAO
{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(ReportQueryDetailsDAO.class);

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    /**
     * @param sql
     * @return
     */
    @Transactional
    public ReportQueryDetail findbySQLId(Long sqlId)
    {
        try
        {
            //Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from REPORT_QUERY_DETAILS where REPORT_QUERY_DETAILS_ID = :sqlId");
            logger.info("select rqd from ReportQueryDetail rqd where rqd.reportQueryDetailsId = " + sqlId);
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select rqd from ReportQueryDetail rqd where rqd.reportQueryDetailsId = :sqlId");
            query.setParameter("sqlId", sqlId);

            List<ReportQueryDetail> results = query.getResultList();
            ReportQueryDetail reportQueryDetail = (ReportQueryDetail) results.get(0);

            return reportQueryDetail;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.debug("Exception:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Excerpt from pom.xml:

```
<java-version>1.6</java-version>
<org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
<org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
<org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
```

Comment: Adding the contents of ReportQueryDetailsDAO class to your question will help.

Comment: @AbdulRabMemon Added the relevant content of the class

Comment: How do you scan your components? Is it a SpringBoot app? What is the folder structure and where `ReportQueryDetailsDAO` resides?

Comment: `ReportQueryDetailsDAO` resides in `package com.xxx.app.dao.report`. There is no `ComponentScan` - annotation in the entire project. It is a `Spring` - mvc app as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well I think instantiating an object with "new" keyword somewhere in ReportQueryDetailsDAO or  ReportEverythingForm could be the cause of problem.

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution which involves auto-wiring the DAO class in the Web-Controller and then setting the DAO class with a setter explicitely before calling any methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing

```
public ReportEverythingForm() {
    //reportQueryDetailsDAO = new ReportQueryDetailsDAO();//HACK FIXME Autowired is null
}
```

to

```
@Autowired
public ReportEverythingForm(ReportQueryDetailsDAO reportQueryDetailsDAO) {
    this.reportQueryDetailsDAO = reportQueryDetailsDAO;
}
```

(I think you need that constructor to set some initial state in your ReportEverythingForm)

Also remove the `@Autowired` annotation from the `ReportQueryDetailsDAO reportQueryDetailsDAO` field

**EDIT**

An other solution is to use the [@PostConstruct](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/) annotation, and delete your constructor. With that you can set the initial state in your `@PostConstruct` annotated method

Comment: This does not explain what is the problem. Constructor injection is just a different approach to replace field injection, why one should work and the other does not?

Comment: I have the following problem trying to apply this solution: `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.xxx.app.form.ReportEverythingForm]: No default constructor found.` This error probably comes from the line in the controller where I autowired the ReportEverythingForm class.

Comment: What Spring version are you using?

Comment: I added an excerpt from pom.xml to my question

Comment: As far as I know in Spring 3.1.1 you don't need to use the Autowired annotation. Can you please try to just remove it from the constructor I posted in my answer?

Comment: The class `ReportEverythingForm` needed to have a default constructor, because it was used as an argument to the controller call. I then autowired the class `ReportQueryDetailsDAO` accessing the database in the controller, and used a setter on `ReportEverythingForm` to set the database class `ReportQueryDetailsDAO`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that `ReportEverythingForm` is instantiated manually through - `new`. The thing is that you can not get `null` on `@Autowired` field - you will get exception on context initialization if you have no bean to autowire. Check in you code that 
`ReportEverythingForm` and `ReportQueryDetailsDAO` is instantiated by spring. You can either define `xml` bean entry or use `@ComponentScan` or use `@Bean` annotation.